# Collatz conjecture - Why does it end and not go on to infinity?

Tags: conjectures, collatz-conjecture

I was messing around with the sequences of odd numbers in the Collatz conjecture, and (unsurprisingly) found a pattern. Basically, I was calculating the number of steps an odd number takes to reach an even number. Just to give you an example:

For the number 31:   31 -> 47 -> 71 -> 107 -> 161 -> **242**
(31 takes 5 steps to reach an even number)

In a table, a pattern appears:

| Number of steps | Odd number |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 5 |
| 3 | 7 |
| 1 | 9 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 1 | 13 |
| 4 | 15 |
| 1 | 17 |

If you were to plot this in a graph, it would look like this:

[Link to graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42IHm.png)

In which case, the biggest number I have found so far is 131 071 which takes 17 steps to get to an even number.

Doesn't this prove that, in a periodic way, the number of steps per odd number increases as the odd number gets bigger? In which case, if you get an infinitely big number, then it would take an infinite amount of steps to get to zero? Does any of this actually mean anything or is just a random pattern?

Comment: If that were the case, then the conjecture would be true because you can separately use induction on the even numbers to conclude the conjecture. While this is plausible, it shouldn’t be in practice easier than proving the conjecture itself.

Comment: Btw, the conjecture was proven *probabilistically*, meaning it is true *almost* everywhere. So while you can expect to see some patterns, you shouldn’t expect that to help you in proving the general conjecture.

Comment: The whole problem with the Collatz conjecture is that it's full of structure and patterns that make it seems to doable but then when you wade into the complications it's suddenly intractable. That's why it's so famous.

Comment: There is no infinitely big number.

Comment: If there were infinitely big numbers, we wouldn't need all that argument, we'd just note in a finite number of Collatz steps, we can't get from an infinitely big number to $1.$

Comment: Note that $131071=2^{17}-1$  If you write the number in binary, each time you iterate on an odd number the number of trailing $1$s is reduced by $1$.  When you run out of trailing $1$s you get an even.  Write your iteration starting from $31$ writing each number in binary to see it happening.

Comment: Give me an example of an infinitely big number. This exercise is designed to help you with your thinking.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews There is no infinitely big natural number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers that set records are of the form $2^k-1$.  Written in binary they consist of $k\ 1$'s  When you do the first iteration you get $\frac {3(2^k-1)+1}2=\frac{3\cdot 2^k-2}2=2^k+2^{k-1}-1$  The last in binary is of the form $10$ followed by $k-1\ 1$'s.  It will still be odd if $k \gt 1$.  Each iteration on an odd number removes one of the trailing $1$'s, so $k$ iterations will get you to an even.  Writing your result from $31$ in binary we get
$$11111 \to 101111 \to 1000111 \to 1101011 \to 10100001 \to 11110010$$
You should be able to convince yourself that adding any multiple of $2^{k+1}$ will not impact the run of trailing $1$'s.  You have shown that we can have an arbitrarily long run of odd numbers at the start, but it is still a finite run.  To get an infinite run of numbers avoiding $1$ you either need to find a loop or find a sequence that never gets below some number.